# Google maps api REQUEST_DENIED when using API restrictions & key

Tags: google-maps

I have been happily using the Geocoding API from Maps for some years, with no problem.  Recently I've made more keys, for different environments, and decided it would be a good idea to add API restrictions to them.

When I add these API restrictions, I suddenly start getting REQUEST_DENIED.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=={lt},{ln}&key={key}

This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key, ...
REQUEST_DENIED
```

**Removing** them **allows** the APIs to be called again.

---

This is the setup for the keys.  We only have 2 APIs enabled, and they are both added to this key.  In this configuration I can't call the Geocoding API.  When I **delete** the restrictions the Key works again, no problem.  I've not set up any other app restrictions.

---

[image: API Restrictions Page]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google is now aware of the bug and it was reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69715011

Please star the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google. Hopefully they will fix the issue soon.

#### UPDATE

The bug was fixed on Google side in March 2018.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well. I think the API Restrictions settings actually prevents the key being used for the listed APIs. In other words, it's opt-out rather than opt-in. However, that's very counterintuitive and not at all clear from the documentation.

Comment: Please see xomena's answer and my comment on it.

Comment: Sorry @user8960608, the bug report wins :(  Didn't want to remove your successful answer, but this one is important.

Answer (score 1):

I too was in a similar position. I would seem like @user8960608's answer might make sense.

I applied some combinations of different restrictions but none of them seemed to make it work. Minus actually removing the any API 'restrictions' altogether.

So whilst I don't know the answer, I can only hypothesise that those restrictions do not work with Geocode at least? Perhaps that table here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis
might indicate that they aren't used yet, or perhaps the docs are yet to be updated.

For now we simply IP restrict the key, not perfect, but its a start.